# Check null value of map

Tags: java

I am getting `map` as result and when I am getting value I need to convert it to `String` like below:

```
a.setA(map.get("A").toString());
```

but if it returns `null` than it throws `nullPointerException`, so I change it with below:

```
a.setA(map.get("A")!=null?map.get("A").toString():"");
```

but there are more than 20 fields for that I am doing the same so I just want to do like below:

```
String val = "";
a.setA(val=map.get("A")!=null?val.toString():"");
```

but it returns `blank` all time, I have just simple question is can't I use variable like this? or is there any other option for doing the same?

Comment: You need parentheses: `a.setA((val=map.get("A"))!=null?val.toString():"");`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use a method. And avoid calling `get()` twice:

```
private String valueToStringOrEmpty(Map<String, ?> map, String key) {
    Object value = map.get(key);
    return value == null ? "" : value.toString();
}
```

...

```
String a = valueToStringOrEmpty(map, "A");
String b = valueToStringOrEmpty(map, "B");
```

Now repeat after me: "I shall not duplicate code".

Comment: Thanks, exactly I was wanted to reduce 'get()'.

Answer (score 4):

with Java 8 you can do the following:

```
a.setA(map.getOrDefault("A", "").toString());
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you create a util method to this like:

```
public String getMapValue(Map m, String a){

    String s = m.get(a);
    if(s == null)
        return "";
    else
        return s;
}
```

Now you just need to call this method:

```
String val = getMapValue(map,"A");
a.setA(val);
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that `val` wont get the value you want until `map.get("A")!=null?val.toString():""` is evaluated, try this instead:

```
String val = "";
a.setA((val=map.get("A"))!=null?val.toString():"");
```

so you get sure that `val=map.get("A")` evaluates before the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
    Map<String,String> map=new HashMap<>();
    Set<String> keySet=map.keySet();
    Iterator it=keySet.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()){
       if(map.get(it)!=null){
           a.setA(map.get(it).toString());
       }else{   
           a.setA(null);
       }
    }
```